# ADF Limitation : Number of COPY Data Activities in One Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have about 25 CSV Files with different columns (BLOB storage) with around ~250 columns each and want to load it Azure SQL DB separate tables(Basic Tier).

Created a Pipeline with 10 COPY Data Activity (CDA) all parallel in One pipeline for a start and executed it. The ADF pipeline just keeps on running without performing any task.  When I reduce the CDA to 7, the pipeline works and loads the data in a mater of seconds. To check if there is any connections limitation with SQL database, executed 3 pipelines simultaneously with 7 CDA each and it worked.

Question here is --> Is there any Restriction/Limitation to the number of CDA we can have in a pipeline. If Yes, what can be done to change it ?

-Thanks

--EDIT   Added Screenshot post applying solution provided to change property for parallel copies.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are limitations.  Since you are going from a Blob file store to an Azure SQL DB, to increase the amount of parallel copies you will need to set the parallelCopies property.

```
"activities":[
    {
        "name": "Sample copy activity",
        "type": "Copy",
        "inputs": [...],
        "outputs": [...],
        "typeProperties": {
            "source": {
                "type": "BlobSource",
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureSQLDBSink"
            },
            "parallelCopies": 32
        }
    }
]
```

From file store to non-file store   - When copying data into Azure SQL Database or Azure Cosmos DB, default parallel copy also depend on the sink tier (number of DTUs/RUs).

- When copying data into Azure Table, default parallel copy is 4.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-features

Comment: Thank you for trying to provide a solution. I tried your method and added a screenshot for better understanding.  It did let me execute more DCA(s). However the time consumed was astronomical. The logs show all DCA executed in around ~19 secs. Then why the pipeline took 9 mins ?

Comment: @Akshay Can you screen shot your monitor details?  If all the Copy activities completed in 19 seconds, but it took 9 minutes for the entire pipeline to complete, did they run sequentially for some reason? We can dig in more if you share your monitor/logs details.

Comment: @Akshay One more thing to try is overriding the default Data Integration Units (DIU) on the COPY Activity.

Comment: Can you guide me if there is a way to check the type of logs that you are looking for.  Adding a new image of "PipeLine Runs" for a particular execution that took 9 minutes. How can I check if they executed sequentially except of the Image that I posted from the Monitor Log ?

Comment: From that screenshot it appears they all fired within a second of each other so they were running in parallel.  If you hover over the copy activities in the monitor you should see a Details icon appear that looks like a pair of eye glasses. Click on that and verify the details.  Look at copy duration, along with queue duration and time to first byte. Something has to be accounting for that 9 minutes if all your COPY activities reported starting within a second of each other.